# Input Strings into Array and then Splitting the Strings into a Single Char Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am writing a program in java that allows a user to enter `n` and puts them strings into an array. Then, the program takes those strings and splits them up into single char characters and places those characters into a new char array.

An example of what I'm trying to do is below:

- Input `n`: 3
- Input strings: `"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"`
- Original Input Array: `[Cat][Dog][Mouse]`
- Desired Output Array: `[C][a][t][D][o][g][M][o][u][s][e]`

There are a few problems that occur with my code when I run it:

1. I get an exception error with the line of code that takes in my input strings. Line of code: `exp[i] = input.nextLine();`
2. Netbeans IDE is telling me it can not find the symbol for the split function I'm trying to use.

I am not sure what is wrong with my code, but I feel like at least the part where I input the strings should be working. I realize I don't have any output code yet, as I am just trying to get the input part working right now. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
public class Strings {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n; //number of strings
  String[] exp = new String[n]; //input strings
  char[] tokens = new char[n]; //individual char characters

  //Gather data

  public void SetNumberStrings(){
      n = input.nextInt();
  }

  public void SetExpressions(){
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
          exp[i] = input.nextLine();
      }
  }

  public void SplitExpressions(){
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
          tokens[i] = exp.split(" ");
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Strings exp1 = new Strings();
       exp1.SetNumberStrings();
       exp1.SetExpressions();
       exp1.SplitExpressions();

  }
}
```

Comment: Why is `SplitExpressions` using `i < exp.length` instead of `i < n` ? If your code is well behaved, those are always the same value. Also, once you receive `n`, _then_ you can build your `String[]`. Before then, you have no idea what length they should be. Similarly, you can't build your `char[]` until you have know the total length of your strings. So for your string gathering, you probably want a List, not an array, since you have no idea how many elements you're going to be dealing with. Fill that from input, _then_ determine `n` and build your `char[]`.

Comment: Your right, I changed the code so that i is less than n instead of exp.length. The function that lets the user type in n comes before the function that builds the String array, so I'm not sure why that part would be an issue. Regarding char[],doesn't the split function split strings until the characters become " " ?

Comment: If you explicitly ask for `n`, you can declare `String[] exp` _once you know what `n` is_. So up top you only say `String[] exp;`, and nothing else, and in `SetNumberStrings` after `n = ...` you can now say `exp = new String[n]` because only now do you actually have a value for `n`. Similarly, You should have `char[] tokens;` up top, because you don't know how many letters there will be until _after_ your user has typed all their strings, at the end of `SetExpressions`. And finally, of course, `exp` is an array: it has no `.split` function. Only elements in `exp` do.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. The array initialization is not working like that. Having `int n;
   //number of strings` as a class field, means it will be initialized
   with 0, resulting in your arrays having a length of 0. To fix this
   you may declare your arrays after giving a value to `n`.
2. At line `tokens[i] = exp.split(" ");` there is indeed a compilation
   error, because you are trying to call the split method on the exp
   array, but the split method is from String class. So you would need
   to call `exp[i].split`
3. `split` method is not doing what you think it's doing. I think you
   are looking for the `toCharArray()` method.
4. `tokens` array should have the length of all the strings that you
   scanned.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your program. The initialisation of class member variables seems to be wrong (considering your requirement). The call to `SetExpressions` in `main` will not alter the members `n`, `exp` and `tokens` as you are expecting. Value of `n` will be 0 by default and it remains so by the time `exp` and `tokens` get initialised. Hence, when you try to assign the input strings to the elements of `exp`, you get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Further, you are trying to invoke `split` method on a `String[]` object (`exp`), which is wrong (a `String` has `split()` method not `String[]`).

If you just trying to take a string of words and convert them all into a `char[]`, then may be you can simply concatenate all the words into a single `String` object, and then do a `toCharArray()` on that.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Strings {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n; //number of strings
  String[] exp; //Fix...This line was causing exception in your program We should not initialize array here because at this point we don't have the length from user
  char[] tokens; //Fix...We are not confirmed of the length of token array at this point

  //Gather data

  public void SetNumberStrings(){
      n = input.nextInt();
  }

  public void SetExpressions(){
      exp= new String[n];
      for (int i = 0; i <n; i++){
          exp[i] = input.next();//.next() function should be used.
      }
  }

  public void SplitExpressions(){
      int length=0;
      int l=0;
      for(int i=0; i<exp.length; i++) {
          length+= exp[i].length();
      }//this loop will calculate the required length for character array
      tokens =new char[length];//Giving length of array here
      for(int i=0; i<exp.length; i++) {
          for(int j=0; j<exp[i].length(); j++) {
              tokens[l]=exp[i].charAt(j);//
              l++;
          }
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Strings exp1 = new Strings();
       exp1.SetNumberStrings();
       exp1.SetExpressions();
       exp1.SplitExpressions();

  }
}
```

I have cleared all the problems in the code. As mentioned in comments.You had initialized all class variables in class, this is not a good programming practice.